# How to make a valid looping script for email recipients in PHP (with PHPMailer)

Tags: php, loops, foreach, while-loop, phpmailer

I want to make an email delivery system to the 2000 email addresses that are registered in the database.

I face the wrong looping problem. So that 1 recipient gets multiple emails.

Please help, thank you

Here is the piece of script:

```
include "phpmailer/classes/class.phpmailer.php";
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Host = "domain.com";
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "no-reply@domain.com";
    $mail->Password = "passsword";
    $mail->SetFrom("no-reply@domain.com","No Reply");
    $mail->Subject = $mail_subject;

    $query_email_list = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM table");

    while($data_email = mysqli_fetch_array($query_email_list)){

        QRCode::png($data_email['email'], $tempdir. $data_email['email'].".png", $quality, $ukuran, $padding);

        $mail_body = file_get_contents('template/template_email_blast.html');
        $mail_body = str_replace('{email}', $data_email['email'], $mail_body);
        $mail_body = str_replace('{nama_agent}', $data_email['agent_name'], $mail_body);
        $mail_body = str_replace('{tempat_duduk}', $data_email['meja'], $mail_body);

        $mail->AddAddress($data_email['email'], $data_email['agent_name']);
        $mail->MsgHTML($mail_body);

        $sent = $mail->Send();
    }
```

Comment: Well it should come as no surprise that `AddAddress()` just keeps adding addresses without removing old ones.

Comment: You should wrap your whole mail generation code in a function, before muddling it with a loop.

Comment: how to removing old ones?

Comment: Base your code on [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps). You're also using a very old version, so upgrade.

Comment: `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';` You should very probably be using `= 'tls'` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since AddAddress() is a method it will add an email on every loop.

You will have to clear the addresses or create a new object in very loop.

The better way is to clear the addresses.

```
$mail->clearAddresses(); // clear all [to] recipients.
$mail->clearAllRecipients(); // clear all recipients [to cc bcc] etc.
```

Updated Code:

```
  while($data_email = mysqli_fetch_array($query_email_list)){

        QRCode::png($data_email['email'], $tempdir. $data_email['email'].".png", $quality, $ukuran, $padding);

        $mail_body = file_get_contents('template/template_email_blast.html');
        $mail_body = str_replace('{email}', $data_email['email'], $mail_body);
        $mail_body = str_replace('{nama_agent}', $data_email['agent_name'], $mail_body);
        $mail_body = str_replace('{tempat_duduk}', $data_email['meja'], $mail_body);
       // $mail->clearAddresses(); // clear all [to] recipients.
        $mail->clearAllRecipients(); // clear all recipients [to cc bcc] etc.
        $mail->AddAddress($data_email['email'], $data_email['agent_name']);
        $mail->MsgHTML($mail_body);

        $sent = $mail->Send();
    }
```

[Reference docs](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_clearAddresses)

Comment: ahhhh, thank you so much, it work well
i just add code $mail->clearAllRecipients();